# 2-round generalized Feistel network

Tags: feistel-network

> Write the decryption of a 2-round generalized Feistel network given below.
>
> $P_i$ denotes plaintext blocks of each 32-bits.
>   $RK_i$ denotes the round keys.
>   $WK_i$ denotes 32-bit keys applied only at the ﬁrst round (whitening keys)
>
> Continue the lines for the decryption.
>
> The whole ﬁgure will input 4, 32-bit plaintext, encrypt it for 2 rounds and continue with decryption and will output the same input
>
> [image: feistel diagram]

Can anyone help me for this question?

Comment: What have you tried?  We generally don't provide much help for people who just do homework dumps on us, with no sign of effort on their part.

Comment: @poncho İ didn't do so i want to learn.

Comment: If two rounds are too tough, why don't you try to invert a single round?

Comment: I didnt do anything i tried but

Answer (score 1):

I will give the 1 round answer which will help complete the question.

Let $X_{1,i},i=0,\ldots,3$ be the 32-bit outputs of the first round, before the swap, numbered left to right. Then,

$$P_2=X_{1,2}, \quad P_0=X_{1,0}$$
and
$$P_1=WK_0\oplus F_0(RK_0,X_{1,0})\quad
P_3=WK_0\oplus F_0(RK_1,X_{1,2}),
$$
The equations for the $P_{i}$ are as above.