# Can a Feistel network have more than two halves, widening the block width?

Tags: algorithm-design, feistel-network

Just to help   form this question, this is a Feistel network:-

[image: Feistel network]

To me this looks like:-

[image: bread]

Why does the generic architecture have to have two halves?  We already have asymmetry in some variants.  As I understand it, the principal security comes from a secure permutation within the round function. All that happens outside of the round function is simple xor and swapping halves.

Could it have more than two halves then? Say five like the bread?  Or perhaps it has to be an even number of plaits /halves, so say four? Or ten? Yes it would mean more rounds to ensure good mixing of halves and be secure, but that's doable. So for example, with six halves of 64 bits each, would you have a 384 bit cipher?  Is there some intrinsic reason why this wouldn't work?

Comment: Clefia block cipher for example

Comment: This guy has 3 thirds in the braid shape, i think two were sufficient for Mr Feistel, and anything more than 2 is a generalized Feistel network https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Permutation-Generators-Based-on-Unbalanced-Feistel-Lee/dae58470063337f307c2f8532ed72903054a181a

Comment: @daniel So you believe that it doesn't matter if the number of plaits is odd or even?

Comment: @PaulUszak I think it's like the number of wings on a plane, you can have 3, or 4, and it will still work, but 2 is the normal amount. Actually this analogy is bad, 2s the number that was picked and studied the most, other numbers might not be a good trade off for some reason I can't think of.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are designs called generalised unbalanced feistel networks which do exactly this.

See the paper by Schneier and Kelsey [here](https://www.schneier.com/academic/paperfiles/paper-unbalanced-feistel.pdf). The CAST cipher, an AES competition entry was an early example.

The article on cryptowiki gives a brief summary [here](http://cryptowiki.net/index.php?title=Generalized_Feistel_networks)

Here is an example:

[image]

Comment: I always thought that unbalanced only meant the split between one half and the other in terms of bit width.  Thank you.

Comment: Not read your paper yet, but two things strike me.  1) Why two different round functions? 2) What's WK?

Comment: It is a whitening key, like in Rijndael. See https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/42632/2-round-generalized-feistel-network/56163#56163 for more